# How to add a new Field in a document in Firebase instead of using DOC.SET

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any method to merge the new field data with the old data in a document instead of using `set` since this is required to update all the field in a documents?

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('path').doc(id).set()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `set` method will override any existing data in the document. You should use `update` method to update an existing document as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#updating-documents):

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<void> updateUser() {
  return users
    .doc('ABC123')
    .update({'company': 'Stokes and Sons'})
    .then((value) => print("User Updated"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user: $error"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `update`.

```js
const res = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('path').doc(id).update({something: true});
```